# YDSE and diffraction

Tags: visible-light, double-slit-experiment

In a single slit diffraction experiment we know that light bends around the edges. So can we treat Young's double slit experiment (YDSE) as a two slit diffraction since we're using two slits in that case and light should bend around edges of both the slits?
I am a bit confused.

Comment: In both cases light doesn't bend but it gets diffracted and in both cases we calculate a superposition of waves from the apertures. This superposition can be extended to any number of slits, slits with different withs, slits filled with partly absorbing or phase shifting materials and to entire 3d holograms.

Comment: You mean to say that both are similar to each other.the only difference in the pattern is due to number of slits.

Comment: The physical principle is exactly the same. In case of the double slit we look at the superposition of all the waves emerging from one slit, in the double slit experiment from two. The technically more important case is that of a large number (hundreds to hundreds of thousands) of slits in a diffraction grating. If you do this over a two dimensional distribution you get black-white holograms that work only with coherent light and three-dimensional scattering can produce color holograms that work with incoherent white light - all for the price of one summation!

Comment: But in YDSE we have bright fringes of same intensity all over the pattern and in a single slit diffraction the intensity decreases as we move away from the centre. Can u pls explain how does this happen?

Comment: The single slit has small side lobes that are not as easy to see as the bright fringes in a double slit experiment, but they both result from interference. You can use tools like wolfram alpha to calculate and plot these functions. Play around with the slit widths and distances to see what the theory predicts. It's always good to get a feel for experiments in physics by messing around with parameters.

Comment: Enter "doubleslit" into wolframalpha.com and enjoy the results.